# Как реализовать скрытие блока кода в зависимости от значение value?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Например есть:

```
    <input type="text" class="qty-input" name="quantity" id="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
```

Его значение естественно может меняться. 
Так вот как удалять или делать не активным вот этот кусок

```
<span class="minus"  border='0'   onclick="jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1);" >-</span>
```

Если value input-а < 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сделал как мне кажется  проще.

```
<span class="minus"  border='0' onclick="a=document.getElementById('quantity').value; if (a>0) { jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1)};" >-</span>
<input type="text" class="qty-input" name="quantity" id="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Для простоты доступа на этот спан (если он 1 на странице) поставить какой нибудь id.

```
<span id="mySpan" class="Minus" ...>
```

На инпуте

```
<input type="text" ... onchange="document.getElementById('MySpan').style.display=(this.value<1 ? 'none':'block')" ..>
```

Ну или добраться до span jQuery методами, самое главное, что бы его не было на экране в его стилях `display` должен стать `none`, для отображения, обычно `block`

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" value="1" />

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeQuantity(1)" id="quantityUp">+</a>
&nbsp; 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeQuantity(-1)" id="quantityDown">-</a>
```

js:

```
changeQuantity = function (n) {
    var $input = $('#quantity'),
        newVal = parseInt($input.val(), 10) + n;
    $input.val(newVal);
    if(newVal<1) {
        $('#quantityDown').hide();
    }else{
        $('#quantityDown').show();
    }
}
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexeyLem/f2o7yzpn/